# MIPS program doesnt work

Tags: assembly, mips

I have problem with my mips program. After enter a 32bit number it displays a message that the number is or is not square. But when you enter number >1000000 the program does not work. Can someone help me please?

Program in mips:

```
.data  
prompt:        .asciiz "\nEnter an integer\n"
squareMessage:  .asciiz " Is square "
nonsquareMessage:   .asciiz " Isnt square "
isntMessage:   .asciiz "Enter possitive number\n "
intMessage:   .asciiz "Number is: "
.text  
main:

loop:
        #print prompt
        la $a0 prompt
        nop
        nop
        addi $v0 $zero 4
        syscall

        #read integer into $t0
        addi $v0 $zero 5
        syscall
        move $t0 $v0
        addi $t1 $zero 1
        beq $t0, 1, vypis
        nop
        nop
        #if cislo mensi nez 1
        blt $t0, $t1, spatne
        nop
        nop
        #if cislo vetsi nez 0
        bgt $t0, $t1, ready
        nop
        nop

ready:      #vypis zadaneho cisla
        la $a0 intMessage
        nop
        nop
        addi $v0 $zero 4
        syscall

        move $a0 $t0
        addi $v0 $zero 1
        syscall

        li $t2, 1 # t2 is our counter (i)
        j for
        nop
        nop
 for:        #for cyclus, zda je zadane cislo mocnina prizozeneho cisla  
        beq $t2, $t0, end # if we are done
        nop
        nop
        mul $t3,$t2,$t2  
        beq $t3, $t0, vypis
        nop
        nop

        #i++
        addi $t2, $t2, 1 # add 1 to t2
        j for
        #nop

end:        #vypis ze zadane cislo neni ctverec
        la $a0 nonsquareMessage
        addi $v0 $zero 4
        j loop
        syscall

vypis:      #vypis ze zadane cislo je ctverec
        la $a0 squareMessage
        nop
        nop
        addi $v0 $zero 4
        j loop
        syscall   
spatne:
        # print enter possitive number
        la $a0 isntMessage
        nop
        nop
        addi $v0 $zero 4

        j loop
        syscall

loopEnd:    jr $ra
```

Program in C:

```
int main(){
int n, i, result;
printf("Enter number:\n");

scanf ("%d",&n);
 if(n<=0){
    printf("Enter possitive number");
 }
 else{

 for(i = 1; i<= n;i++){
    result = i * i;
    if(result == n){
        printf("Is square");
        return 0;
    }
 }
 printf("Isnt square");
  }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: May be when you do this `result = i * i;`, result is more than INT32_MAX if number >1000000 and not square. So you have an integer overflow.

Comment: 1000000 = 0xF4240, takes 20 bits so the result of the multiply requires 40 bits?  So definitely an integer overflow.  You are using an int so you basically have 31 bits, so you cant accept a number that has more than 15 significant bits